# Cannot remove E-mail in geary account list

Tags: gnome, email, mail, client, geary

Actually I wanted to try geary so I added an E-mail to try it out. now I want to remove my E-mail from geary accounts list, but "-" button is off and I cannot remove it (*also I searched about it but no luck!*). On the other hand after so many tries I also removed `~/.local/share/geary/[E-mail]` directory but it keep loading my E-mail account...

Now How can I totally remove my E-mail and then unistall it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many accounts are there in total? If you are trying to remove the last one, you'll need to either add a second account, or manually remove the account by deleting `~/.config/geary/ACCOUNT_ID` as well as `~/.local/share/geary/ACCOUNT_ID` (replacing `ACCOUNT_ID` with the actual id of the account, of course), per [Bug 714572](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=714572).

Update:

If you have installed Geary from Flathub, those paths are a little bit different: `~/.var/app/org.gnome.Geary/config/geary/ACCOUNT_ID` and `~/.var/app/org.gnome.Geary/data/geary/ACCOUNT_ID`.

Comment: Thanks, I remove that two configuration files and it worked great!, But the new matter is why gnome and geary development team don't want to add this feature? (since it reported at 2013). On the other hand where can I connect with gnome development team (I have some ideas for gnome future which can be a good feature!)

Comment: No problem. It hasn't been fixed yet because Geary is being developed by volunteers in our spare time rather than paid employees, and we just haven't had the time to fix it yet. If you'd like to [help out](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary/Contribute), we could certainly make some faster progress!

Comment: I tried doing this, but my email account is still there, like a zombie...

Comment: I couldn't manually delete these files. But I could achieve the workaround by adding a second (different) account and then removing the first one.

Comment: Perhaps you have some other installation laying around (e.g. flatpak)? Try this command to find it out: `find / -type d -name geary`

Comment: Yup, probably a Flatpak installation. I just updated the answer to include the relevant paths.

Comment: I have not used any Flatpak installations. This was not the issue.

Comment: My `geary` dirs: `/home/john/.config/geary
/home/john/.local/share/geary
/home/john/.cache/geary
/usr/lib/geary
/usr/share/doc/geary
/usr/share/gnome/help/geary
/usr/share/geary`

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the `~/.config/geary` and so forth folders. I tried `sudo apt purge geary` and reinstalling it. I tried resetting the settings for the app in dconf editor. Nothing worked.

Eventually, I did a grep on everything to find my e-mail address and somehow Geary was looking at the accounts in `~/.config/evolution`, `~/.cache/evolution`, and `~/.local/share/evolution` even though I've never used Evolution, so if you can't remove an account from Geary no matter what you do, try deleting those directories.